# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not getting called

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I tap on a cell, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't getting called. When I press and hold on a cell, it'll highlight the cell, but as soon as I take my finger off, the highlight will disappear. And when I tap with two fingers - one finger on one cell, one finger on another cell - THEN `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` finally gets called and the one cell remains highlighted.

I stripped out all my custom table view cell code and turned it into a completely generic table with a stock `UITableViewCell`. Still the same problem.

Yes, the data source and delegate are set. No, there aren't any weird delegate methods that are calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath`.

Here's the code for the table view.

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 75.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 75.0f) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = _backgroundColor;
```

And here's the code I stripped the cell down to.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello!";

return cell;
```

I've been through all the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` discussions on here and tried all the recommended solutions. And I can't find anyone mentioning the problem I'm seeing here, where didSelectRowAtIndexPath DOES get called, it's just very intermittent or you have to use two fingers at once.

Comment: Can you share your cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation??

Comment: See edit. I stripped it all the way down to the bare minimum, was still seeing the same issue.

Comment: i check your code it working i am not getting your issue

Comment: If you have a stripped down project that demonstrates this, it would be helpful if you could post it somewhere.

Comment: pos the code thats not working

Comment: Do you have `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` implemented by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the method is

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    }
```

In the view controller in .h

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Yes to both of those.

Comment: @bmueller : then you should add the complete cellForRow code for this to be answered